# Python IOError: invalid mode: w - my procedure can't write on external file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, io, syntax-error, jinja2

In the code bellow, when the procedure dupdateNumBookPg(b, fp) is called (in this line: updateNumBookPg(geted_numBook, geted_numFinalPage) ) I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\CG\Documents\udacity\contract\main.py", line 174, in get
    updateNumBookPg(geted_numBook, geted_numFinalPage)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Documents\udacity\contract\main.py", line 62, in updateNumBookPg
    doc = open("numbookpg.txt", "w")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 589, in __init__
    raise IOError('invalid mode: %s' % mode)
IOError: invalid mode: w
INFO     2012-07-05 22:26:54,964 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /your_contract?person=Raj%20Koothrappali&nacionality=Indian&profession=physicist&maritalStatus=unmarried&SSN=22222&driverLicense=%2011111&email=&witness=&owner=&contractType=House%20Rental%20Contract&address=%20New%20Delhi&numBook=44&numInitialPage=300&numFinalPage=300 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have a .txt file in the same directoty and my code can open and split it content, but not write on it updating it content. What is producing this error? What's wrong with my IO statment?

Thanks for any help!

```
doc = open("numbookpg.txt", "w")
doc.write(newNumBookPg)




# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

import os

import webapp2

import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

import re

from google.appengine.ext import db

USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,20}$")
def valid_person(person):
    return USER_RE.match(person)

PASS_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
def valid_SSN(SSN):
    return PASS_RE.match(SSN)

EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
def valid_email(email):
    return EMAIL_RE.match(email)

import time

import datetime


def getNumBookPg():
    doc = open("numbookpg.txt")
    numBookPg = []
    numbers = doc.read().split()
    for n in numbers:
        numBookPg.append(n)
    return numBookPg

numBookPage = getNumBookPg()

def updateNumBookPg(b, fp):
    newNumBookPg = b + ' ' + str(int(fp) + 1) + ' ' + str(int(fp) + 1)
    doc = open("numbookpg.txt", "w")
    doc.write(newNumBookPg)

def dateToday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    todayDay = str(today.day)
    todayMonth = str(today.month)
    monthExt = {'1':' January ', '2':'February', '3':' March ', '4':'April', '5':'May', '6':'June', '7':' July ', '8':'August', '9':'September', '10':'October', '11':'November ', '12':'December'}
    todayYear = str(today.year)
    return(todayDay + ' of  ' + monthExt[todayMonth] + ' of ' + todayYear)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        numBook = numBookPage[-3]
        numInitialPage = numBookPage[-2]
        numFinalPage = numBookPage[-1]
        template_values = {"person": "",
                                       "nacionality": "",
                                       "SSN": "",
                                       "driverLicense": "",
                                       "email":"",
                                       "person_error": "",
                                       "SSN_error": "",
                                       "driverLicense_error": "",
                                       "address": "",
                                       "email_error": "",
                                       "numBook": numBook,
                                       "numInitialPage": numInitialPage,
                                       "numFinalPage": numFinalPage,
                                       }
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

##    def write_form(self, text_write):
##        self.response.out.write(text_write)

    def post(self):
        person_name = self.request.get("person")
        user_nacionality = self.request.get('nacionality')
        user_profession = self.request.get('profession')
        user_maritalStatus = self.request.get('maritalStatus')
        user_SSN = self.request.get('SSN')
        user_email = self.request.get('email')
        user_driverLicense = self.request.get('driverLicense')
        person_error = ""
        SSN_error = ""
        driverLicense_error = ""
        geted_email_error = ""
        address = self.request.get('address')
        contractType = self.request.get("contractType")
        owner = self.request.get("owner")
        witness = self.request.get("witness")
        numBook = self.request.get("numBook")
        numInitialPage = self.request.get("numInitialPage")
        numFinalPage = self.request.get("numFinalPage")

        if (person_name and valid_person(person_name)) and (user_SSN and valid_SSN(user_SSN)) and ((not user_email) or (user_email and valid_email(user_email))):
            a = Person(firstName = person_name,
                                   nacionality = user_nacionality,
                                   maritalStatus = user_maritalStatus,
                                   profession = user_profession,
                                   SSN = int(user_SSN),
                                   driverLicense = int(user_driverLicense)
                                   #address = user_address
                                   )
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/your_contract?person=%s&nacionality=%s&profession=%s&maritalStatus=%s&SSN=%s&driverLicense=%s&email=%s&witness=%s&owner=%s&contractType=%s&address=%s&numBook=%s&numInitialPage=%s&numFinalPage=%s' % (person_name, user_nacionality, user_profession, user_maritalStatus, user_SSN, user_driverLicense, user_email,
witness, owner, contractType, address, numBook, numInitialPage, numFinalPage))

        else:
            if not person_name or not valid_person(person_name):
                person_error = "Oh no!!! this person name isn't valid!"
            if not user_SSN or not valid_SSN(user_SSN):
                SSN_error = "Oh no!!! SSN isn't valid!"
            if user_email and not valid_email(user_email):
                geted_email_error = "Oh no!!! e-mail isn't valid!"
            template_values = {"person": person_name,
                                "nacionality": user_nacionality,
                                "maritalStatus": user_maritalStatus,
                                "profession": user_profession,
                                "SSN": user_SSN,
                                "driverLicense": user_driverLicense,
                                "email": user_email,
                                "person_error": person_error,
                                "SSN_error": SSN_error,
                                "driverLicense_error": user_driverLicense,
                                "address": address,
                                "email_error": geted_email_error}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class your_contractHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        geted_person_name = self.request.get('person')
        geted_user_nacionality = self.request.get("nacionality")
        geted_user_profession = self.request.get("profession")
        geted_user_maritalStatus = self.request.get("maritalStatus")
        geted_user_SSN = self.request.get('SSN')
        geted_user_email = self.request.get('email')
        geted_user_driverLicense = self.request.get('driverLicense')
        geted_person_error = ""
        geted_SSN_error = ""
        geted_driverLicense_error = ""
        geted_address = self.request.get('address')
        geted_owner = self.request.get("owner")
        geted_witness = self.request.get("witness")
        geted_contractType = self.request.get("contractType")
        geted_dateToday = dateToday()
        your_contract = jinja_environment.get_template('your_contract.html')
        geted_numBook = self.request.get('numBook')
        geted_numInitialPage = self.request.get('numInitialPage')
        geted_numFinalPage = self.request.get('numFinalPage')
        updateNumBookPg(geted_numBook, geted_numFinalPage)
        your_contract_values = {"person":geted_person_name,
                                "nacionality":geted_user_nacionality,
                                "maritalStatus": geted_user_maritalStatus,
                                "profession": geted_user_profession,
                                "SSN":geted_user_SSN,
                                "driverLicense":geted_user_driverLicense,
                                "address":geted_address,
                                "email":geted_user_email,
                                "contractType":geted_contractType,
                                "dateContract":geted_dateToday,
                                "numBook":geted_numBook,
                                "numInitialPage":geted_numInitialPage,
                                "numFinalPage":geted_numInitialPage,
                                }
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(your_contract.render(your_contract_values))

class Person(db.Model):
    firstName = db.StringProperty(required = True)
#    lastName = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    nacionality = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    maritalStatus = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    profession = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    SSN = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    driverLicense = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
#    address = db.PostalAdressProperty(required = True)
#    condition = db.StringProperty(required = False, choices=set(["buyer", "seller", "renter", "owner", "witness"]))

##class Acts(db.Model):
##    firstPart = db.StringProperty(required = True)
##    secondPart = db.StringProperty(required = True)
##    contractNumber = db.IntegerProperty(required = False)
##    contractDate = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
##    contractDraft = db.TextProperty(required = True)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/your_contract', your_contractHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to the file system is not allowed by app engine.

Comment: So, the only alternative is use datastore, creating a database?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore for how to use the blobstore to write files.